# Trying to Upload Facebook offline evet using python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to Upload facebook offline event using python script, But it ends up with exit code zero, but not doing any thing.
can any one suggest me what are possible solutions or what's wrong with the code.

```
import Json
Import pandas as pd

from facebook_business.adobjects.offlineconversiondataset import OfflineConversionDataSet
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
class FacebookService:
def __init__(self):
    self.api = FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id='myappid', app_secret='MYappsec',


                                   access_token='My Access Token')
    self.offline_dataset = OfflineConversionDataSet('2763361757229939')
    
def upload_offline_conversion(self, example_events_file):
    df = pd.read_csv("UPLOADS.csv", sep=";", dtype=object)
    # df columns are 'order_id', 'value', 'event_time', 'event_name', 'email', 'phone', 'fn', 'ln', 'currency'
    df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
    # event times have to be sent in UNIX timestamp format
    df['event_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['event_time']).astype(int) / 10 ** 9).astype(int).astype(str)
    df['match_keys'] = df.apply(lambda row: json.dumps({k: [row[k]] if k in ['email', 'phone'] else row[k] for k in ['email', 'phone', 'fn', 'ln'] if pd.notnull(row[k])}), axis=1)
    del df['email']  # deleting match_keys single columns since they are now useless
    del df['phone']
    del df['fn']
    del df['ln']
    
    data = df.to_dict(orient="records")
    batch_limit = 2000  # Maximum number of events permitted in a single call
    for i in range(0, len(data), step=batch_limit):
        params = {
            'upload_tag': 'purchases_upload',  # This must be a string, unique for all your uploads, that will let you identify them
            'data': data[i:i+batch_limit],
        }
        self.offline_dataset.create_event(params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we need to create/update itens in facebook API, Facebook API suggest us a different approach to perform batch operations, try to use this following approach:

```
def remote_create_itens(itens,api):

  batch_limit = 50

  try:
    for batch_itens in generate_batches(itens, batch_limit):
        api_batch = api.new_batch()
        for item in batch_itens:
            def callback_success(response, item=None):
                logging.debug(f"Item {item['id']} successfully read.")
                print(f"Item {item['id']} successfully read.")
            callback_success = partial(callback_success, item=item)

            def callback_failure(response, item=None):
                logging.debug(f"Failed to read {item['id']}.")
                print(f"Failed to read {item['id']}.")
                raise response.error()

            callback_failure = partial(callback_failure, item=item)
            item.remote_create(batch=api_batch,success=callback_success,failure=callback_failure)

        #Execute the create
        api_batch.execute()
  except Exception as err:
      logging.error("Error in create: "+str(err))
      logging.exception(e, exc_info=True)
```